# Convert the big integer/decimal to a valid IPv6 address in javascript

Tags: javascript

```js
function covertToIPv6(IP)
{
       var ip = "";
       ip = ((IP >> 112 ) & 0xFFFF) + ":" + ((IP >> 96 ) & 0xFFFF) + ":" + ((IP 
         >> 80 ) & 0xFFFF) + ":" +((IP >> 64 ) & 0xFFFF) + ":" + ((IP >> 48 ) & 
         0xFFFF) + ":" + ((IP >> 32 ) & 0xFFFF) + ":" + ((IP >> 16 ) & 0xFFFF) + 
       ":"+( IP & 0xFFFF);

       console.log(ip);
}

covertToIPv6(63802943797675961899382738893456539648);
```

Hi I am trying to convert the big integer or decimal number to valid `IPv6 address`
I have tried the below function for it.

But this is giving all zero sets

```
covertToIPv6(63802943797675961899382738893456539648);
```

> Ans: 0:0:0:0:0:0:0:0

Comment: That number might be too big?

Comment: `63802943797675961899382738893456539648 > Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER // true`

Comment: @evolutionxbox it's *exceptionally* too large It's double the *length* of `Number.MAX_SAFE_INTEGER` (`9007199254740991`) and also suffers from the fact that any bitwise operations would further truncate the number to 32 bit.

Comment: Maybe in future [bigint](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/BigInt) will help?

Comment: `>> 112` I think that might be an issue, considering bit-shifts work on 32-bit ints.

Comment: Hi ,do we have any other approach to handle such big numbers in java script

Comment: Any other approach or flow to convert the big int/decimal to valid Ipv6 address.
I have used the below function to convert the ipv6 address to numerical value, 
function getv6Integer(ip){
 var parts = [];
 ip.split(":").forEach(function(it) {
     var bin = parseInt(it, 16).toString(2);
     while (bin.length < 16) {
         bin = "0" + bin;
     }
     parts.push(bin);
 })
 var bin = parts.join("");
 var dec = bigInt(bin, 2).toString();
 console.log(dec);
}
now i want to convert it back to ipv6 address

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you really can't use `BigInt` or use a string representation, here's a working function that reconverts your big integer into an IPv6 address. The integer, however, must be in a string representation for this to work.

```js
var divide = function(dividend, divisor) {
  var returnValue = "";
  var remainder = 0;
  var currentDividend = 0,
    currentQuotient;

  dividend.split("").forEach(function(digit, index) {
    // use classical digit by digit division 
    if (currentDividend !== 0) {
      currentDividend = currentDividend * 10;
    }
    currentDividend += parseInt(digit);

    if (currentDividend >= divisor) {
      currentQuotient = Math.floor(currentDividend / divisor);
      currentDividend -= currentQuotient * divisor;
      returnValue += currentQuotient.toString();
    } else if (returnValue.length > 0) {
      returnValue += "0";
    }

    if (index === dividend.length - 1) {
      remainder = currentDividend;
    }
  });

  return {
    quotient: returnValue.length === 0 ? "0" : returnValue,
    remainder: remainder
  };
};

var convertToIPv6 = function(input, base) {
  base = base || 10;
  var blocks = [];
  var blockSize = Math.pow(2, 16); // 16 bit per block

  while (blocks.length < 8) {
    var divisionResult = divide(input, blockSize);

    // The remainder is the block value
    blocks.unshift(divisionResult.remainder.toString(base));

    // The quotient will be used as dividend for the next block
    input = divisionResult.quotient;
  }

  return blocks.join(":");
};

// Examples
["63802943797675961899382738893456539648",
 "16894619001915479834806084984789761616",
 "734987203501750431791304671034703170303"
].forEach(function(input) {
  console.log("Input:", input);
  console.log("IP address (decimal):", convertToIPv6(input));
  console.log("IP address (hex):", convertToIPv6(input, 16));
});
```

Comment: Hi corschdi, Thanks for your explanation and examples